# Mensagem de alerta em SESSION

Tags: php, session, easyphp

Tenho um sistema que funciona perfeitamente no computador(A) que foi desenvolvido e, ao passar pro computador(B) servidor com as mesmas configurações, a mesma versão do EasyPHP e etc, apresentou muitos, mas muitos erros.

Um desses erros é logo no login e diz:

> "Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
>   in (diretorio/logica-usuario.php) on line 4."

Esse é o logica-usuario.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
function verificausuario(){
    if (!isset($_SESSION["usuario_logado"])) {
    header("location: login.php");
    die();
   }
}
function verificausuario() {
    if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario_logado"])) {
    header("location: login2.php");
    die();
   }
}
function logaUsuario($nome) {
    $_SESSION["usuario_logado"] = $nome;
}
function logout() {
    session_destroy();
}

?>
```

A linha 4 é esse session_start(); mas não tem nada de errado com ele, afinal, é esse sistema todo bugado é o mesmo sistema que roda perfeitamente no computador(A) e rodava no computador(B) antes de ele ser formatado.

Comment: Essa página deve estar sendo incluída em outra 2 ou mais vezes... normalmente esse erro vem do uso de include / require tente substitui-los respectivamente para include_once / require_once

Comment: Talvez você incluiu no documento, outra página que já tinha dado um `session_start`, o `PHP` dispara esse aviso para te alertar, caso queira sanar isso, revise a lógica e tire-os de onde não precisa, em ultimo caso coloque um @ na frente do `session_start` para ocultar o warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcionou quando eu fiz isso:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
function verificausuario(){
    if (!isset($_SESSION["usuario_logado"])) {
    header("location: login.php");
    die();
   }
}
function verificausuario() {
    if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario_logado"])) {
    header("location: login2.php");
    die();
   }
}
function logaUsuario($nome) {
    $_SESSION["usuario_logado"] = $nome;
}
function logout() {
    session_destroy();
}

?>
```